# Не заносятся данные в массив

Tags: php

Есть массив $dateArr и $userArr Почему в массив в цикле заносится всегда только последний ключ???

```
 foreach($dateArr as $num => $dates) {
        echo $num;

        $date = $dates['date'];
        $userTrueArr = ee($date);
        $data = array();

            foreach($userArr as $user) {
                if(!in_array($user,$userTrueArr)) {
                    $data[$user][] = "0";
                    echo 'data['.$user.']['.$num.'] = "0"<br>';
                } else {
                    $price = getSumm($user,$date);
                    $data[$user][] = $price;
                    echo 'data['.$user.']['.$num.'] = "'.$price.'"<br>';
                }
            }echo "<br>";

}echo "<pre>";print_r($data);echo "</pre>";exit;
```

Comment: @Антон Хавчиков, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас $data инициализируется на  каждом шаге внешнего цикла.